# javascript - can't change an image's position

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm trying to change a position of a image that I have in HTML by using javascript. I can actually get it working if I have the following code:

```
function main()
{
    var catOne = document.getElementById("cat1");
    catOne.style.left = cat1.getX().toString() + "px";
    catOne.style.top = cat1.getY().toString() + "px";
}
```

but when I change the code to this:

```
var catOne = new Cat("cat1", 300, 100);

function main()
{

    catOne.setUp();
}
```

it doesn't work. and I dont know why, but it only gives me an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

This is my Cat class in javascript:

```
function Cat(id, x, y)
{
    this.cat = document.getElementById(id);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Cat.prototype.setUp = function ()
{
    this.cat.style.left = this.x.toString() + "px";
    this.cat.style.top = this.y.toString() + "px";
};

Cat.prototype.getX = function ()
{
    return this.x;
};

Cat.prototype.getY = function ()
{
    return this.y;
};
```

Comment: works fine for me... see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gEm3a/

Can you write a jsfiddle with your code showing the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` means your `catOne` does not exist in the DOM tree.

You should instantiate the Cat class when the DOM is ready (or on window load).
I don't know why you need that `main()` function but when does it execute? It should also execute when the DOM is ready.

```
var catOne;
function main() {
    catOne.setUp();
}

window.onload = function() {
    catOne = new Cat("cat1", 300, 100);
    main();
}
```

I also suggest that you set the `position` of your cat to `absolute` if you are positioning it like that in your `setUp()` function. (I think you are already doing this with your CSS):

```
Cat.prototype.setUp = function ()
{
    this.cat.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.cat.style.left = this.x.toString() + "px";
    this.cat.style.top = this.y.toString() + "px";
};
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/mpUkm/) is the fiddle.
Other than that your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
var catOne = new Cat("cat1", 300, 100);
catOne.setUp();
```

works just fine.

I don't quite get it how You managed to get error You mentioned

link: http://jsfiddle.net/Z74mM/